# DeMorgan's Rule and Probability Proof

Tags: probability

[image]

My attempt at this was to first re-write the LHS of the given inequality so that I can use DeMorgan's rule. After that and some algebra, I was able to bound my expression to the probability of the intersection of the complement of n-events is greater than or equal to $1$ minus the probability of the sum of n events is greater than or equal to 1 - n + the sum of $a_i$ from $i=1$ to $n$. After this I get stuck, as I do not know how to relate the intersection of the complement of n-events to the intersection of n-events, in fact, I don't even think there's a general way to do it. Anyway, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you rewrite the left hand side of the inequality as :
$P(\cap A_i) = 1 - P((\cap A_i)^c) = 1 - P(\cup (A_i)^c)$, where the last equality follows from De Morgan's law.

Now, note that $P(\cup(A_i)^c) \leq \sum P(A_i^c)$, from the given inequality.

Finally, note that $P(A_i^c) = 1 - P(A_i)  \leq 1 - (1 - a_i) \leq a_i$ for all $i$.

Can you combine things and finish from here?

Comment: Holy crap, that's so trivial yet elegant. I'm actually dumb lol

Comment: It is fine, it slips through us occasionally. You are welcome.